# How to pass Reactive variables among different templates in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have 2 separate templates:

```spacebars
<template name = "MusicControl">
  <!-- Some Logics here -->
</template>

<template name = "MusicSystem">
  <!-- Some Logics here ("click" event) -->
</template>
```

I have 2 JavaScript files associated with these 2 templates.

What I want is that if an event occurs (`"click"` event) on the **MusicControl** template, it sets some sort of global variable (but **not** `Session` variable) so that I can access it in another template as a helper function.

How to implement in **Reactive-Dict** in Meteor?

Do not worry I have the **helper functions defined for both the template in their respective js**.

And one thing, these `<templates>` are independent of each other, I just want to listen the event in `<template 1>` on <`template 2>` by using some sort of global variable.

Answer (score 3):

A simple version of @zim's answer is:

**HTML (actually Spacebars)**

```spacebars
<template name="Parent">
    {{> Child1 sharedVar1=sharedVar}}
    {{> Child2 sharedVar2=sharedVar}}
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

// Just initialize the variable. Could also be within the scope of a template.
var myReactiveVar = new ReactiveVar();

Template.Parent.helpers({
    // This is what will be sent to Child1 and Child2.
    sharedVar: function () {
        return myReactiveVar;
    }
});

Template.Child1.helpers({
    myValue: function () {
        // As usual, this will be reactive.
        return Template.instance().data.sharedVar1.get();
    }
});

Template.Child2.events({
    'event selector': function (event, template) {
        // This change will trigger an autorun of Child1 myValue helper.
        template.data.sharedVar2.set(myNewValue);
    }
});
```

(of course you can split these into several JS files)

Example with a demo app using Meteor 1.6.1 and Blaze: https://github.com/ghybs/meteor-blaze-templates-share-data

Comment: This isn't working for me in Meteor 1.6.1, as sharedVar1.get() comes out as undefined inside of Child1

Comment: @Houseman: although this answer is almost 1 year old, I just tested it in Meteor 1.6.1 and [it still works perfectly](https://github.com/ghybs/meteor-blaze-templates-share-data). Feel free to open a new question should you need help in implementing it.

Comment: Thanks for putting in that extra effort! I was able to get it working

Comment: @Houseman thank you for your feedback, I am glad you got your app working!

Answer (score 1):

for this scenario, i generally use a reactive variable owned by the parent, whose job it is to coordinate among its children. i would not use a global variable here.

below are the basics. Child1 sets the shared var and Child2 uses it. the parent owns it. Child1 and Child2 have no relationship to one another.

```
<template name="Parent">
    {{> Child1 sharedVarSetter=getSharedVarSetterFn}}
    {{> Child2 sharedVar=sharedVar}}
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.Parent.onCreated(function() {
    this.sharedVar = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.Parent.helpers({
    sharedVar() {
        return Template.instance().sharedVar.get();
    },

    getSharedVarSetterFn() {
        let template = Template.instance();

        return function(newValue) {
            template.sharedVar.set(newValue);
        }
    }
});

Template.Child1.onCreated(function() {
    this.sharedVarSetterFn = new ReactiveVar(Template.currentData().sharedVarSetter);
});
```

and somewhere in Child1 (helper, event handler, what have you):

```
let fn = template.sharedVarSetterFn.get();

if (_.isFunction(fn)) {
    fn(newValue);
}
```

here, i've shown just 1 shared var. but if you have multiple, a reactive dict could work the same way.

Comment: The `child1` code looks overly complicated… IIRC, just sharing a `ReactiveVar` between 2 templates, with one setting it and the other getting it, is enough for such scenario

Comment: @ghybs, that's what i'm doing, sharing a reactive var between two (child) templates. then the question is always: who owns it? here, it's the parent, which has the benefit that what the children need is passed down, rather than the children reaching out for something they need. if it's a global, e.g., then the children are reaching out. from a design perspective, i like to pass things from parent from child.

Comment: the other common pattern is that a child dispatches an event, caught by a parent, who then ensures the value is passed to the other child. but from what i've seen, that's not really a pattern in Meteor. so i've taken to having the parent pass down a callback function to 1 child.

Comment: IIRC just share the parent's `ReactiveVar` between the 2 children, then 1 sets it, the other one gets it, and the `autorun` is happy… I do not have a Blaze project to check now, but it should just work…

Comment: @ghybs you should write it up as an answer. i use the above pattern for more complicated things, so it's my kind of default goto. but yours is a more simple way to solve the OP's issue.