# Call method from other template after rendering

Tags: templates, meteor

Using Meteor I got a template which consists of 2 other templates A & B.
A got a `<select>` Tag and B got a `<canvas>` on which something will drawn depending on the select of template A.

When the selection changes, A should call someMethod` of B, and this method should get some data from the db and then draw the canvas. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Simply using `Template.B.someMethod = function (bla) ...` and then in the JS of A calling `Template.B.someMethod(hi)` causes an error because `someMethod` accesses the DOM `canvas` Element of B which is not rendered when A changes for the first time at the loading.

What would be a fitting way to call the method? Or should I merge the two templates together?

Answer (score 1):

no need to combine A and B templates. the purpose of the parent here is to coordinate data changes between A and B. i.e. you won't be calling functions on B, but rather giving it the data it needs so it can respond.

P (the parent) can push into A a function that A calls when its data changes via the select. P can then push that data into B through Meteor's normal reactivity. B can then respond to that change.

e.g.

```
<template name="P">
    {{A changeHandler=getChangeHandler}}
    {{B selection=selectedData}}
</template>
```

P.js:

```
Template.P.onCreated(function() {
    this.data = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.P.helpers({
    getChangeHandler() {
        let template = Template.instance();

        return function(data) {
            template.data.set(data);
        }
    },

    selectedData() {
        return Template.instance().data.get();
    }
});
```

A.js:

```
Template.A.onCreated({
    this.changeHandler = new ReactiveVar(Template.currentData().changeHandler); // i think this is right
});
```

and whenever A data changes:

```
let changeHandlerFn = template.changeHandler.get();

if (_.isFunction(changeHandlerFn)) {
    changeHandlerFn(updatedData);
}
```

Comment: Reminds me of that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148872/how-to-pass-variables-among-different-templates-in-meteor/43160902#43160902 :-)

Comment: heh, you're right. there's a simpler solution, isn't there? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Besides @zim's answer, you can also use a variation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687311/5108796:

**HTML** (actually Spacebars)

```spacebars
<template name="Parent">
    {{> Child1 sharedVar1=sharedVar}}
    {{> Child2 sharedVar2=sharedVar}}
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

// Just initialize the variable. Could also be within the scope of a template.
var myReactiveVar = new ReactiveVar();

Template.Parent.helpers({
    // This is what will be sent to Child1 and Child2.
    sharedVar: function () {
        return myReactiveVar;
    }
});

Template.Child1.events({
    'change select': function (event, template) {
        // This will trigger a re-execution of Child2 autorun.
        template.data.sharedVar1.set(myNewValue);
    }
});

Template.Child2.onCreated(function () {
    var sharedVar2 = this.data.sharedVar2;

    this.autorun(function () {
        // As usual, this is reactive.
        var newValue = sharedVar2.get();

        // Perform some operation using newValue…
    });
});
```

(of course you can split these into several JS files)

Comment: Thanks!
I definitly like your answer more because it's simpler than @zim but thanks to you too! Will try it as soon as possible!