# Transfer data from one Template to other in Meteor without using Session

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

i am trying to Transfer data from one Template to another Template and both template are child  in Meteor main thing is i can transfer data using Session but i don't want to use it .
So what is other way to do so?

Comment: You would probably be interested in [How to pass variables among different templates in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148872/how-to-pass-variables-among-different-templates-in-meteor/43687311#43687311)

Comment: @ghybs it's pass data in one template , Using ReactiveVar we can not pass data to other Template.

Comment: why not? maybe I do not understand your objective: do you need reactivity or not?

Comment: Elaborate on the case please :) Are those templates parent/child if so - from which template to which are you trying to pass the data? Are those templates on the same level?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var data;
```

**Note** : `var data` is global for your app at location -> **`client/lib/js/file.js`**

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this answer please?

Comment: If you define variable in file using `var` then that variable is available only in that file where it is defined.